# What all is required for SQL server compact 4.0 to be used on another system when it is merged with windows form in .net

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, frameworks, sql-server-ce

I have an Demo Application made on windows form in c# and I have used Sql Server Compact 4.0 as its database. Now I need to use the same application on another system which doesn't have visual studio or Sql-Server installed in it. Now what all I need to install on that system so that my application runs effectively ? 
I don't want to install visual studio or SQL-server in it and for that only i have used SQL-server compact 4.0 but its asking for visual studio service pack-1 to be installed.
I have already installed .net framework and sql server compact 4.0 in it.
Please help me with solutions and any suggestions will also be heartly accepted.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to deply the SqlCompact database file to the other system.
Make sure that the path is correct.

You don't need SQL Server to be installed for SQL ServerCompact to work.

You also don't need Visual STudion. Just need the .Net Runtimes.

Comment: the other system has .net framework already installed in it. but its not running on the other system and when installing sql server compact 4.0 in it its asking for visual studio sp1 to be installed first. And its working fine on the system with visual studio installed in it.

Comment: For your application to work, u don't neef SQL Server Compact Installed on the user's system.